# Looking for a Halachic/Hashkafic Sefer about Shirah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, music

Music seems to play a predominant role in Jewish life, looking at the common practice of Shabbos zemiros or the wide variety of tunes during davening as some examples. Some of this bleeds over into the realm of Halacha, looking at Sotah 49a and Gittin 7a and the Poskim to each one regarding music nowadays (post-Churban). As such, I was wondering if anyone came across a Sefer that went through the various sources and discusses the different Hashkafos on what music does and what its role should be in one’s life.

I did come across such a Sefer a while ago, called [*Through Music and Song*](https://www.amazon.com/Through-Music-Song-Torah-perspective/) by Rabbi Elysha Sandler (a Sefer I’ve quoted before on this site). However, I felt this Sefer was a bit too Chassidish and Kabbalistic for me. What I’m looking for in an answer here is a Sefer in the same vein as that one, but geared more toward a Litvak crowd.

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s quite clear enough what I’m looking for. If anyone is confused, please ping me and I’ll try to clarify further.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Music-Kabbalah-Matityahu-Glazerson/dp/1568219334 - never read it, but if anybody could answer your questions it would be Rabbi Glazerson. (May be worth trying to talk to him.)

Comment: IIRC [R. Moscato](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Moscato) has such a discussion in one of the early pieces of his [Nefutzot Yehudah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/6084).